# Java Web Start shortcuts not working after Java update

Tags: java, java-web-start, shortcut

After updating to **Java 1.8**, all my Java Web Start desktop shortcuts don't work any more, because of the wrong path to the `JRE`.

For example:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.x.x_xx\....
```

Is there a way to update these paths automatically after a Java update?

Comment: set the `JAVA_PATH` or call `javaws.exe` with a complete path.

Answer (score 0):

Java Web Start is included in the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) .The desktop short cut may be pointing to your previous version .

Also go to Start > Settings > Control Panel > Double click on the Java icon. ...
Click on the General tab. Click on the View button from the Temporary Internet Files section. Make sure you the previous version is unchecked